# Inconsistent return values in Laravel collections

Tags: php, json, sorting, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am working on a thread based messaging system.

I have a simple query to return all of the messages for a specific thread like that:

`$t->messages->sortByDesc('updated_at')`

While passing this to the `return response()->json()`, if it has one message the return value is an `array`. While if it has more than one messages the return value is an `object` of objects like that `{0 => {messageattribs}, 1 => {messageattribs}}`.

I would like to know why is this, and why it doesn't follow the array without the index keys patterns as in the first case.

Comment: This is a multi-dimensional array, it's the same thing. The first is 1 row, while the second has multiple rows.

Comment: @MinaYoussef the question is why it cannot be [{messageattribs},{messageattribs}] instead of {0 => {messageattribs}, 1 => {messageattribs}}. The array without the index keys would be the consistent  array with the first case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is how Eloquent works, you can use custom collections if you like http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections#custom-collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Laravel keeps the indexed array, as you are facing.

To "remove" that indexes just call some couple of methods more: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby

```
$t->messages->sortByDesc('updated_at')->values()->all();
```

It is going to return a set/collection just like you want.

Hope it helps!

Best wishes.

PS: Let me invite you to a Laravel course, you may learn something new there: [Laravel Course](https://www.programarya.com/php-with-laravel-create-advanced-applications-while-learning-laravel)